# Select rows with a column value that occurs at least two times and having different values in another column and finally order by updated time

Tags: oracle

I need to select a column which have same values with exactly three counts and having different values in another column and finally order by updated_time.

For this example below, I need to fetch only the value 15 from column1

```
column1 column2 updated_time
12        21    2019-01-05 01:36:50.995476
12        21    2018-04-05 01:36:50.995476
12        21    2019-02-05 01:36:50.995476
11        25    2019-03-05 01:36:50.995476
11        25    2019-02-05 01:36:50.995476
11        25    2019-04-04 01:36:50.995476
11        25    2019-05-05 01:36:50.995476
15        27    2019-01-05 01:36:50.995476
15        26    2019-01-05 01:36:50.995476
15        29    2019-02-05 01:36:50.995476
16        29    2019-04-03 01:36:50.995476
17        31    2019-04-03 01:36:50.995476
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of `column1` you must `group by column1`.

> same values with exactly three counts

means `count(*) = 3`, and

> having different values in another column

means `count(distinct column2) = 3`:

```
select * from tablename 
where column1 in (
  select column1
  from tablename 
  group by column1
  having
    count(*) = 3
    and 
    count(distinct column2) = 3
)
order by updated_time
```

Comment: if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it